# A function that adds new columns to a dataframe

Tags: r

I need a function which adds a new column (with constant values) to a dataframe `df`. My attempt so far is this:

```
f = function(df, col.name, col.value){
  df$col.name = col.value
  print(df)
 }
```

A typical input would be:

```
f(df, "New column", NA)
```

This would give me a new column with value NA, however, it would be named `col.name`.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Should the function return your data.frame, or modify it in the parent environment? Plus, I think it should warn you when you supply an existing column in col.name.

Comment: I'm not using environments yet as I am just beginning in R so I guess I'm just looking for the function to return the data frame.

Comment: You are picking the wrong answer. The "$<-" function is already built in to R. It gets translated into one version of `[[<-`. Failing to understand that aspect of the language is a major cause of noob-frustration. You might also want to look at the `within` function.

Comment: Have you got any recommendations on how I could learn about 'this aspect of the language'. Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

R has in-built functions for this sort of thing, namely `$<-` for assigning a single column of data.

```
> test <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6)

> test
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6

> `$<-`(test,"new_column",NA)
  a b new_column
1 1 4         NA
2 2 5         NA
3 3 6         NA
```

As @MatthewLundberg says in the comment below, you could assign this to your new function if you want to avoid the funky function name:

```
> f <- `$<-`
> f(test,"new_column",NA)
  a b new_column
1 1 4         NA
2 2 5         NA
3 3 6         NA
```

Comment: I am just playing with this now. But it seems that `$<-` is like `transform` in base R. Am I wrong?

Comment: @jazzurro - it functions similarly to `transform`, yes. It's directly analogous to taking a copy of the data.frame, adding a column, then returning that copy. `"$<-"(test,"new_column",NA)` is the translation of `test$new_column <- NA`

Comment: @thelatemail I see. Then, when would `$<-` shine more? Is there any case we prefer/need the function?

Comment: @jazzurro, it's sometimes handy in writing particular shorthand scripts where you want the whole object returned, like the `class<-` version this question links to.

Comment: @thelatemail Got it. That makes sense. I try to use this function with some dummy data frames today. Thanks for your lessons. I learned two important things from you today.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = function(df, col.name, col.value){
  df[[col.name]] <- col.value
  print(df)
 }
```

If you want to accommodate @flodel's and @theodore's comments you could use something like:

```
f <- function(df, col.name, col.value, overwrite = FALSE){

    if ( col.name %in colnames(df) ) {
        if ( overwrite ) {
            warning(paste("column", col.name, "overwritten!"))
        } else {
            stop(paste("column", col.name, "already exists!"))
        }
    }

    df[[col.name]] <- col.value 
    return(df)
}
```

Comment: thanks. out of interest do you know why my attempt didn't work?

Comment: As pointed out, it is really preferred to just return `df`. If you use `print(df)`, the function will still return `df` so you can assign it, but the new data.frame will be printed no matter what, even if you assign it. Most people would agree that this is not a desirable feature. If instead the function just returns `df`, the new data.frame will still be printed if you are running from the command line of an interactive session and the output is not assigned to anything.

Comment: @user32259 your attempt didn't work because indexing by `$` cannot (easily) use the contents of a variable for the index.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the name of the new column, you can do this:

```
test <- data.frame(a=1:3,b=4:6)
test$c = c(1:3)
```