# Changing class of data frame columns using strings

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where all the columns have the `character` class but many of the columns should be of numeric or integer class. I also have a character vector containing the desired class for each column e.g.

```
classes <- c("integer", "integer", "numeric", "character", "logical", "numeric", ... )
```

I am looking for a way to set the class of each column quickly using this `classes` vector without looping.

I was hoping there would be a way to do this similar to naming, e.g.

```
names(df) <- names
```

where `names` is a `character` vector, or in my case

```
class(df) <- classes
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `Map`:

```
df <- data.frame(V1=letters[1:3],
                 V2=c("1","2","3"),
                 V3=c("1.1","2.2","3.3"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

classes <- c("character","integer","numeric")

str(df)
#'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ V1: chr  "a" "b" "c"
# $ V2: chr  "1" "2" "3"
# $ V3: chr  "1.1" "2.2" "3.3"

df[] <- Map(`class<-`, df, classes)

str(df)
#'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ V1: chr  "a" "b" "c"
# $ V2: int  1 2 3
# $ V3: num  1.1 2.2 3.3
```

Comment: This is a nice technique. One of the lessons from today's posts. I have seen `length<-` as well. I think Richard Scriven used it. Could you tell me what `<-` is doing here?

Comment: `"class<-"(variable,"newclass")` is essentially doing `class(variable) <- "newclass"` - it's an assignment function. I could have written it longhand like: `Map(function(x,y) {class(x) <- y; x}, df, classes)`

Comment: Ah I see. thank you very much for the clear explanation. I already upvoted. But it seems that I need another one here. Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: @jazzurro - no worries - just remember that lots of things in R are functions that may not appear to be on the surface - e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308871/a-function-that-adds-new-columns-to-a-dataframe/14309231#14309231