# Applying a vector of classes to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have a character vector of classes that I would like to apply to a dataframe, so as to convert the current class of each field in that dataframe to the corresponding entry in the vector. For example:

```
frame <- data.frame(A = c(2:5), B = c(3:6))
classes <- c("character", "factor")
```

With a for-loop, I know that this can be accomplished using lapply. For example:

```
for(i in 1:2) { frame[i] <- lapply(frame[i], paste("as", classes[i], sep = ".")) }
```

For my purposes, however, a for-loop cannot work. Is there another solution that I am missing?

Thank you in advance for your input!

**Note:** I have been informed that this might be a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435873/changing-class-of-data-frame-columns-using-strings). And, yes, my question is similar to it. But I have looked at the class() approach before. And it does not seem to effectively deal with converting fields to factors. The lapply approach, on the other hand, does it well. But, unfortunately, I cannot utilize a for-loop in this instance

Comment: What's the source of the data? Why don't you apply the classes when reading the data in rather than applying them later?

Comment: Also, can you use `lapply` without an explicit `for` loop? Like `frame[] <- lapply(seq_along(frame), function(x) { FUN <- paste("as", classes[x], sep = "."); match.fun(FUN)(frame[[x]]) })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not averse to using `lapply` without a `for` loop, you can try something like the following.

```
frame[] <- lapply(seq_along(frame), function(x) { 
  FUN <- paste("as", classes[x], sep = ".")
  match.fun(FUN)(frame[[x]])
})

str(frame)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ A: chr  "2" "3" "4" "5"
#  $ B: Factor w/ 4 levels "3","4","5","6": 1 2 3 4
```

However, a better option is to try to apply the correct classes when you're reading the data in to begin with.

```
x <- tempfile()                          # Just to pretend....
write.csv(frame2, x, row.names = FALSE)  # ... that we are reading a csv

frame3 <- read.csv(x, colClasses = classes)

str(frame3)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ A: chr  "2" "3" "4" "5"
#  $ B: Factor w/ 4 levels "3","4","5","6": 1 2 3 4
```

---

Sample data:

```
frame <- frame2 <- data.frame(A = c(2:5), B = c(3:6))
classes <- c("character", "factor")
```

Comment: Thanks much! This approach worked perfectly. I am building a Shiny app that will, in part, allow the user to load a data file and specify the desired class type for each variable in that file. Combining your code with an isolate() function does the trick.